# Hiding Map Elements Outside of Neatline in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, layouts, design

I have a map layout in ArcMap 10.1 that incorporates a neatline that is offset from the edges of the layout by about an inch on the inside. Certain elements of my map extend beyond the neatline and layout view.

Does anyone know of a way to clip or hide the elements that extend between the neatline and edge of the layout when exporting the map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [dataframe clipping](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s90000000q000000) located in the Dataframe Properties > Data Frame tab.  You can clip the dataframe by current visible extent, outline of features, outline of selected graphics or by custom extent.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways you could do this, but the first that springs to mind is to draw a rectangle using the drawing toolbar that matches your extent and follows the neatline.  You can then use that graphic element to clip your layers accordingly.

Comment: Or this might help:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//010300000094000000